# Return data from a delegate in Cordova iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, delegates

I am very new to iOS and Cordova. I am working on an application that reads data from a bluetooth device and using the vendors SDK. I am calling a function from js into iOS that automatically calls a delegate. The delegate basically reads the tags that I am reading with the hand held device. Now while I keep reading the tags with the hand held device, I need to continuously send the read tags back to the client. The signature of the delegate looks like this:

```
-(void)transponderReceived:(NSString *)epc crc:(NSNumber *)crc pc:(NSNumber *)pc rssi:(NSNumber *)rssi fastId:(NSData *)fastId moreAvailable:(BOOL)moreAvailable
```

Is there a way for me to return this data as its being read to the client through the auto-called delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the function from javascript and you create the plugin result you have to make it keep creating callbacks

```
CDVPluginResult* result = nil;
result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:returnInfo];//returnInfo is a NSDictionary with the data to be returned, you can return an NSString or an NSArray instead
[result setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:callbackId];//You will have to store the callbackId somewhere so you can use it on the deletage, like creating a @property on the .h
```

So you can keep sending plugin results from the delegate